# MailChimp API Webhook Headers

Tags: azure, azure-functions, mailchimp, webhooks, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I wanted to use an Azure HTTP function combined with a MailChimp Webhook.

Azure expects a security token to be sent with requests to the function as a header.

I am unable to see how to specify headers when creating the MailChimp Webhook.

Does anyone know if it's possible?

The other option is to somehow configure the function not to expect a security token?

Comment: Can't it be just passed as HTTP query parameter (so, as part of webhook URL)?

Comment: I cannot find any azure documentation to say that can be done. It appears it needs to be a header :(

Comment: You can call HTTP with `https://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function>?code=<ApiKey>`

Comment: @Mikhail you are correct! Thank you so much. Please suggest this as answer so I can give you points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Function Webhook is essentially an HTTP triggered Azure Function. It can accept the secret `code` as HTTP query parameter:

1. Create an HTTP triggered function.
2. Set authentication to `Function`
3. Click on `Get function URL` button to get your URL in format `https://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function>?code=<ApiKey>`
4. Put this URL into Mailchimp's webhook Callback URL

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the security on the function using AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous

```
[FunctionName("Unsubscribe")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Unsubscribe([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

**SEE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER ABOVE. THIS IS NOT ADVISABLE**